# Ingesting Mainframe data into Hadoop using Sqoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, sqoop, mainframe

I found Sqoop 1.4.6 has connectivity to Mainframe It can pull data from Mainframe PDS and put into either HDFS/Hive/Hbase or Accumulo.

I was wondering if it supports packed decimal datatype or just simple datatypes? 
Can somebody help me to understand what all Mainframe file formats are supported by Sqoop 1.4.6.

Thanks in advance

Reference
https://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.6/SqoopUserGuide.html

Comment: And the documentation says?

Comment: In document its just mentioned It call pull data form PDS, Im not sure if it call pull packed decumal data too

Comment: it also says "The records in a dataset can contain only character data"

Comment: "The import-mainframe tool imports all sequential datasets in a partitioned dataset(PDS) on a mainframe to HDFS. A PDS is akin to a directory on the open systems. **The records in a dataset can contain only character data.** Records will be stored with the entire record as a single text field." Seems to me it answers your question.

Comment: Ha. So I just wasted my time looking up the documentation for you. Well, you have your answer.

Comment: sorry for that..So it means it supports only simple text files?

Comment: Yes. Just change all non-DISPLAY fields to DISPLAY. I'd recommend the sign separate and an actual decimal point, or a "scaling factor" (a new field with number of decimal places), whichever is more convenient for the target. It seems odd that it only works from a PDS (which is not a directory in any real sense, though treated as a directory for things like ftp).

Comment: As Bill said PDS is like a directory and used to hold a particular type of object (program, script or parameters). All "Members" of a PDS must have the same attributes, so you can not store Program and shell-scripts in the same PDS. It is a bit like the bin or etc directories in Unix/Linux

Comment: For what its worth there are commercial programs and open source projects for moving Cobol-Data to Ha. I do not know how good any of them are

Comment: thanks Bill and Bruce

Answer (score 2):

Hi as per my analysis Packed decimal are not suported, infact if the file has packed decimal data rest of the data is messed up as well. Please refer to http://rbheemana.github.io/reality-of-sqoop-mainframe/ for more details.

Comment: since you are much familiar with ingesting mainFrame data to hdfs.. which way we should use to get the big mainFrame files to hdfs on weekly basis..

Answer (score 0):

As per the documentation "9.2.6 File Format" ...

"... By default, each record in a dataset is stored as a text record with a newline at the end. Each record is assumed to contain a single text field with the name DEFAULT_COLUMN. When Sqoop imports data to HDFS, it generates a Java class which can reinterpret the text files that it creates.  ..."